# EF Code First & SQL Server Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

In ASP.NET MVC3, how do I display data from a SQL Server view when I am using EF Code First?

Comment: What stops you from doing it the same way as regular table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the name of the View as the name of the Table.

Comment: He is using Code first = no Entity model.

Comment: *Where* do you use the name of the View?

Comment: @anon - Either as a class name or in your Fluent API `ToTable` function