# Reading data from DB View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm new to asp.net MVC. I'm want to retrieve data from a database view and map it to my model. Model class has same set of properties as of the view. Is there a way by which i can get data from db view instead of a table (table gets created automatically due to code first).

My model looks like this:

```
public class Product{

    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
    public int ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Title")]
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
};

public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products 
    { 
        get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same like with tables! Did you try?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107879/ef-code-first-sql-server-views

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Code First to map to a view, just tell Code First that it's a table and it will use the same SQL against the view that it would for a table. Obviously, if you try to update that entities, you will get an exception if the view is not updatable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dbml? drag your dbo.View to dbml, use as you use a table, but can not add and update.

```
public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductDBContext ()
        : base("MyConnection") //web.config
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

// Your View:
// CREATE VIEW dbo.Product
// AS
// SELECT dbo.ProductProfile.ID, dbo.ProductProfile.ProductCode, dbo.ProductTitle.ProfileID, dbo.ProductTitle.ProductTitle 
// FROM   dbo.ProductProfile INNER JOIN
//          dbo.ProductTitle ON dbo.ProductProfile.ID = dbo.ProductTitle.ProfileID
//
[Table("dbo.Product")]  
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
    public int ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Title")]
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
}
```